# combobox is taking focus

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, textbox

I have a problem that i really cannot solve. It's been hours of searching. I have this simple tkinter window with one combobox, one figure on a `FigureCanvasTkAgg` and a Matplotlib TextBox. The thing is that i want to print something on console when i press Enter (on the TextBox). I do this by using `text_box.on_submit()` command. TextBox can be found here [Matplotlib Widgets](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.TextBox). If i don't touch the combobox, it works well. However when i pick something (an option) from combobox, it takes focus and enter (sumbit command) does not work for the TextBox. I cant event write on the TextBox but instead when i type i write on the combobox. And even if i click on the TextBox, i can't solve it...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

win = tk.Tk()

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,7,3,6,9,3,6])
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=win)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas.draw()

textboxax = plt.axes([0.92, 0.35, 0.06, 0.07])
text_box = TextBox(textboxax, '', initial='',color='gray',hovercolor='white')
text_box.on_submit(lambda x: print('helloo'))

cb = ttk.Combobox(win,values=['red','white','black','yellow','blue'])

cb.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to overcome this might be to set focus to the widget that is clicked using `.focus_set()`

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

def focus_widget(event):
    event.widget.focus_set()

win = tk.Tk()

win.bind('<Button>', focus_widget)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,7,3,6,9,3,6])
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=win)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas.draw()

textboxax = plt.axes([0.92, 0.35, 0.06, 0.07])
text_box = TextBox(textboxax, '', initial='',color='gray',hovercolor='white')
text_box.on_submit(lambda x: print('helloo'))

cb = ttk.Combobox(win,values=['red','white','black','yellow','blue'])

cb.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. It did solve my problem.!!!